# SQL Lag distinct - to the previous different value

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, lag, distinct-values, hana-sql-script

I have the following simplified by many columns table.

```
 Person     Period           Cost_Center Previous_Cost_Center
----------- ---------------- ----------- ----------------------
123         2019003          1            
123         2019004          1            
123         2019005          2            
123         2019006          2            
123         2019007          3
```

For each Person, I would like to find his Previous Cost Center and save it in the corresponding column. The previous Cost Center has to be different from the current one.

What I would like to get:

```
Person      Period           Cost_Center Previous_Cost_Center
----------- ---------------- ----------- ---------------------
123         2019003          1           NULL 
123         2019004          1           NULL 
123         2019005          2           1 
123         2019006          2           1                     <----- Problematic row 
123         2019007          3           2
```

Standard LAG() function over the period would actually output:

```
Person      Period           Cost_Center Previous_Cost_Center
----------- ---------------- ----------- ---------------------
123         2019003          1           NULL 
123         2019004          1           NULL 
123         2019005          2           1 
123         2019006          2           2                     <----- Problematic row 
123         2019007          3           2
```

What I would like to have in a problematic row is the last different Cost_Center value which is 1 and not 2.
What I thought of using is to check if the previous Cost_Center is different:

```
          CASE
                WHEN
                    LAG ( Cost_Center ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Period ) != Cost_Center
                THEN
                    LAG ( Cost_Center ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Period )
                ELSE
                    Previous_Cost_Center
                END
            AS Previous_Cost_Center,
```

But then I end up without a Previous_Cost_Center value in row 4 at all.
How can this be archived using SQL? How can I take over the last different Cost_Center value to save it in Previous_Cost_Center sorting by Period?

Comment: You can use a scalar subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions, but it is trickier than necessary because the `ignore null`s option is not available.

First, you want to assign a grouping to adjacent values of the same group.

Second, you want to give the *first* value in the grouping the previous cost center.

Third, you want to "spread" that value through the entire group.

```
select t.*,
       max(case when immediate_prev_cost_center <> cost_center then immediate_prev_cost_center
           end) over (partition by person, cost_center, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
                     ) as prev_cost_center
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by person order by period) as seqnum,
               row_number() over (partition by person, cost_center order by period) as seqnum_2,
               lag(cost_center) over (partition by person order by period) as immediate_prev_cost_center
        from t
       ) t;
```

The difference of row numbers defines the group.  The `max()` spreads the previous value throughout the group.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f07b5dd9776bf5c001cf8e547302920d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon! Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Replace #test with your table name. Its just select and you can change it to update. Please test this out as you will be having different scenarios.

```
SELECT s.person,
       s.period,
       s.cost_center,
       CASE WHEN z.person IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE z.cc END AS Previous_Cost_Center
FROM   #test s
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                  FROM   (SELECT t1.*,
                                 t2.cost_center               cc,
                                 Row_number()OVER (partition BY t2.person, t1.period ORDER BY t2.period DESC) RN
                          FROM   #test t1
                                 JOIN #test t2
                                   ON t1.person = t2.person
                                      AND t1.period > t2.period
                          WHERE  t1.cost_center <> t2.cost_center)s
                  WHERE  rn = 1
         )z
              ON s.person = z.person
                 AND s.period = z.period
```