# LAG with multiple repeating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, distinct-values

I have a table with multiple encounters. Each encounter can have multiple encounter groups, and there can be 1 or more activities within the encounter group.

| encounter_id | encounter_group_id | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1000 | check in |
| 100 | 1000 | process |
| 100 | 1000 | check out |
| 100 | 1001 | check in |
| 100 | 1001 | check out |
| 100 | 1002 | check in |
| 100 | 1002 | transform |
| 100 | 1002 | process |
| 100 | 1002 | load |
| 100 | 1002 | check out |
| 100 | 1003 | check in |
| 100 | 1003 | terminate |

I'm trying to use the LAG function to get this result

| encounter_id | encounter_group_id | prev_group_id | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1000 | NULL | check in |
| 100 | 1000 | NULL | process |
| 100 | 1000 | NULL | check out |
| 100 | 1001 | 1000 | check in |
| 100 | 1001 | 1000 | check out |
| 100 | 1002 | 1001 | check in |
| 100 | 1002 | 1002 | transform |
| 100 | 1002 | 1001 | process |
| 100 | 1002 | 1001 | load |
| 100 | 1002 | 1001 | check out |
| 100 | 1003 | 1002 | check in |
| 100 | 1003 | 1002 | terminate |

I'm using this statement, but in each case the lag only gets the encounter group from the previous row.

```
select  encounter_id, 
        encouter_group_id, 
        LAG(encounter_group_id) OVER (ORDER BY encntr_group_id),
        activity
from encounter_activity
```

The results set looks like this instead:

| encounter_id | encounter_group_id | prev_group_id | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1000 | NULL | check in |
| 100 | 1000 | 1000 | process |
| 100 | 1000 | 1000 | check out |
| 100 | 1001 | 1000 | check in |
| 100 | 1001 | 1001 | check out |
| 100 | 1002 | 1001 | check in |
| 100 | 1002 | 1002 | transform |
| 100 | 1002 | 1002 | process |
| 100 | 1002 | 1002 | load |
| 100 | 1002 | 1002 | check out |
| 100 | 1003 | 1002 | check in |
| 100 | 1003 | 1003 | terminate |

Hopefully I'm just missing a minor tweak to be able to show the previous group correctly

Comment: `ORDER BY encntr_group_id` Where is the field/column `encntr_group_id` defined ??

Comment: It is system derived.  The activities are grouped together under single encounter_group_id.  Multiple activities can make up an encntr_group, and each encntr can have multiple encntr_groups.  There are other columns that I am not displaying because they contain more information about the activity, but I left them out to simplify the table in my question

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `Nth_Value()`. You might just need a subquery or cross apply: `(select max(encntr_group_id) from encounter_activity ea2 where ea2.encounter_id = encounter_activity.encounter_id and ea2.encounter_group_id < encounter_activity.encounter_group_id)`

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67074234/1322268

Comment: Thanks everyone.  All suggestions were helpful.  There are 15M+ rows in this table and growing.  This is the solution that performed best for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070499/sql-lag-distinct-to-the-previous-different-value

Answer (score 1):

Since LAG takes a second argument, you can calculate it in a subquery as the dense_rank() on the encounter_group_id partition:

```
select d.encounter_id, d.encounter_group_id, 
    lag(encounter_group_id, rnk) over(order by encntr_group_id)
        as prev_group_id, d.activity
from (
    select d.*,
    dense_rank() over(partition by encounter_group_id order by encntr_group_id) as rnk
    from encounter_activity d
) d
;

100 1000            check in
100 1000            process
100 1000            check out
100 1001    1000    check in
100 1001    1000    check out
100 1002    1001    check in
100 1002    1001    transform
100 1002    1001    process
100 1002    1001    load
100 1002    1001    check out
100 1003    1002    check in
100 1003    1002    terminate
```